# spring file upload without commons-fileupload.jar

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

Literally, is it possible to make file upload without using commons-fileupload.jar in spring framework?
(if so, how can I make without it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In Servlet 3.0 environment you can use `StandardServletMultipartResolver`. See Spring documentation for more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver-standard

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I want.